# QFileSystemModel with Checkboxes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qfilesystemmodel

So, I have this simple PyQt5 code which is essentially a file explorer. I need to be able to select arbitrary files or groups of files (directories and all of the children). I would like to:

1. Add a Checkbox next to each item
2. If an item is checked/uncheck and has sub-items, the state of the sub-items should be set to the state of the item. So if you check a directory, everything underneath it should also get checked.
3. When an items check state is changed, directly or indirectly, I need to invoke a callback with the full path (relative to the root) of the item.

I am essentially building a list of selected files to process.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileSystemModel, QTreeView, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 file system view - pythonspot.com'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.initUI()
    
    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        
        self.model = QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setRootPath('')
        self.tree = QTreeView()
        self.tree.setModel(self.model)
        
        self.tree.setAnimated(False)
        self.tree.setIndentation(20)
        self.tree.setSortingEnabled(True)
        
        self.tree.setWindowTitle("Dir View")
        self.tree.resize(640, 480)
        
        windowLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        windowLayout.addWidget(self.tree)
        self.setLayout(windowLayout)
        
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The QFileSystemModel doesn't load the contents of a directory until explicitly requested (in case of a tree view, it onyl happens when the directory is expanded the first time).

This requires to carefully verify and set the check state of each path recursively not only whenever a new file or directory is added (or renamed/removed), but also when the directory contents are actually loaded.

In order to correctly implement this, the check states should also be stored using file paths, because when the contents of a directory change some indexes might be invalidated.

The following implementation should take care of all written above, and emit a signal only when an item state is actively changed *and* the parent state is changed, but *not* for the children items of a checked directory.
While this choice might seem partially incoherent, it's a performance requirement, as you cannot get the individual signals for each subdirectory (nor you might want to): if you check the top level directory, you might receive thousands of unwanted notifications; on the other hand, it might be important to receive a notification if the parent directory state has changed, whenever all items become checked or unchecked.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class CheckableFileSystemModel(QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel):
    checkStateChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, bool)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.checkStates = {}
        self.rowsInserted.connect(self.checkAdded)
        self.rowsRemoved.connect(self.checkParent)
        self.rowsAboutToBeRemoved.connect(self.checkRemoved)

    def checkState(self, index):
        return self.checkStates.get(self.filePath(index), QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)

    def setCheckState(self, index, state, emitStateChange=True):
        path = self.filePath(index)
        if self.checkStates.get(path) == state:
            return
        self.checkStates[path] = state
        if emitStateChange:
            self.checkStateChanged.emit(path, bool(state))

    def checkAdded(self, parent, first, last):
        # if a file/directory is added, ensure it follows the parent state as long
        # as the parent is already tracked; note that this happens also when 
        # expanding a directory that has not been previously loaded
        if not parent.isValid():
            return
        if self.filePath(parent) in self.checkStates:
            state = self.checkState(parent)
            for row in range(first, last + 1):
                index = self.index(row, 0, parent)
                path = self.filePath(index)
                if path not in self.checkStates:
                    self.checkStates[path] = state
        self.checkParent(parent)

    def checkRemoved(self, parent, first, last):
        # remove items from the internal dictionary when a file is deleted; 
        # note that this *has* to happen *before* the model actually updates, 
        # that's the reason this function is connected to rowsAboutToBeRemoved
        for row in range(first, last + 1):
            path = self.filePath(self.index(row, 0, parent))
            if path in self.checkStates:
                self.checkStates.pop(path)

    def checkParent(self, parent):
        # verify the state of the parent according to the children states
        if not parent.isValid():
            return
        childStates = [self.checkState(self.index(r, 0, parent)) for r in range(self.rowCount(parent))]
        newState = QtCore.Qt.Checked if all(childStates) else QtCore.Qt.Unchecked
        oldState = self.checkState(parent)
        if newState != oldState:
            self.setCheckState(parent, newState)
            self.dataChanged.emit(parent, parent)
        self.checkParent(parent.parent())

    def flags(self, index):
        return super().flags(index) | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole and index.column() == 0:
            return self.checkState(index)
        return super().data(index, role)

    def setData(self, index, value, role, checkParent=True, emitStateChange=True):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole and index.column() == 0:
            self.setCheckState(index, value, emitStateChange)
            for row in range(self.rowCount(index)):
                # set the data for the children, but do not emit the state change, 
                # and don't check the parent state (to avoid recursion)
                self.setData(index.child(row, 0), value, QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole, 
                    checkParent=False, emitStateChange=False)
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            if checkParent:
                self.checkParent(index.parent())
            return True

        return super().setData(index, value, role)


class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.tree = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        layout.addWidget(self.tree, stretch=2)

        model = CheckableFileSystemModel()
        model.setRootPath('')
        self.tree.setModel(model)
        self.tree.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.tree.header().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)

        self.logger = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.logger, stretch=1)
        self.logger.setReadOnly(True)

        model.checkStateChanged.connect(self.updateLog)
        self.resize(640, 480)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda: self.tree.expand(model.index(0, 0)))

    def updateLog(self, path, checked):
        if checked:
            text = 'Path "{}" has been checked'
        else:
            text = 'Path "{}" has been unchecked'
        self.logger.appendPlainText(text.format(path))
        self.logger.verticalScrollBar().setValue(
            self.logger.verticalScrollBar().maximum())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = Test()
    test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! Exactly what I was looking for.